# SSRS Group Sort Using Group Variable

Tags: vba, sorting, reporting-services, expression

I'm looking to sort group `Part` using variable `Coverage`. The variable's expression:

```
=( IIF(ISNOTHING( SUM(Fields!OnhandQty.Value) ), 0, SUM(Fields!OnhandQty.Value)) + 
   IIF(ISNOTHING( Fields!WIP.Value ), 0, Fields!WIP.Value)
) / IIF(ISNOTHING( SUM(Fields!RequiredQuantity.Value) ), 0, SUM(Fields!RequiredQuantity.Value) )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm able to save report (using Report Builder) with no errors, but I get the error:

*The processing of SortExpression for the table ‘TablixCustomer’ cannot be performed. The comparison failed. Please check the data type returned by the SortExpression. (rsProcessingError)*

Why?

Comment: Could you explain the sort logic that you want, there may be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression `SUM(...Value)` will fail if `.Value` is ever null and becomes a String value of `#error`. So try changing your expressions to this: Note that it checks the value before aggregating the value instead of aggregating before checking for null.

```
=( SUM(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!OnhandQty.Value), 0, Fields!OnhandQty.Value)) + 
   IIF(ISNOTHING( Fields!WIP.Value ), 0, Fields!WIP.Value)
) / SUM(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!RequiredQuantity.Value), 1, Fields!RequiredQuantity.Value))
```

Comment: This will fail is RequiredQuantity is nothing as it will attempt a divide by zero. This issue was present in the OP's expression though.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I edited to avoid divide by zero error.